# What if someone says "Ich bin" as a self-introduction?

Tags: usage, phrase, idiomaticity, spoken-language

If someone who doesn't really know German says

> Ich bin [name]

instead of

> Ich heiße ...

to introduce him/herself, is this an error in German and how odd does it sound?

Comment: Which error do you mean? _"Ich bin [name]"_ is a common way of introducing oneself.

Comment: Many German courses (at least the one I took) teach that _"Ich heiße [name]"_ is the correct way and that _"Ich bin [name]"_ is strictly wrong — maybe because of not wanting to teach students a less formal version. That's where I suspect the confusion comes from.

Comment: @xish: Sorry, but I can hardly believe that this definite nonsense is taught in **many** German courses. Maybe you over-generalize from the **one** German course you took?

Comment: @Björn. Or the other way round? How many German courses do you know? (Please add a twinking eye here. I posted this chiefly because I found the possibilty of changing perspectives intriguing.)

Comment: None for foreigners, but that is why I say _"I cannot believe ..."_ whereas xish confidentially says _"Many German courses teach ..."_.

Comment: The one I took taught that, and it would seem the OP was clearly independently told this by someone as well. I did indeed qualify my statement with "at least the one I took" to make it clear that my statement was only conjecture from my experience interacting with German teaching material and other German learners. This isn't the first time I've seen this question.

Comment: @xish ... interesting why they teach that "Ich bin..." is *strictly* wrong. Many things in languages depend on circumstances, situation, pragmatics. You would usually rather give recommendations where a certain form of expression is appropriate and where not.

Comment: @xish, whatever ... The point is that _"Ich bin [name]"_ is a common way of introducing oneself. There is absolutely nothing wrong, not even slang, youth language, or dialect.

Comment: Yeah. My instructor was an older woman who was born and lived in Baden-Württemberg some 30 years before moving to the US. She did indeed correct several times someone saying "ich bin..." and after this conversation, I wonder if her age had something to do with it. Is it possible that "ich bin..." would not have been acceptable 20 or 30+ years ago? She was in her mid-50s at the least.

Comment: @xish Beginners courses teach this as the correct form, indeed. (Disqualifyng the *sein*-form). This doesn't mean the courses are in a German speaking country.

Comment: Here is a hypothesis: It happens (quite often) that stuff about foreign languages (or languages in general) that once has been published in a textbook becomes entrenched in the teaching of that language because authors of textbooks seldom write those books from scratch (and based on real-world knowledge), they rather reuse what they find in existing books. And thus various unrealistic concepts are perpetuated. (Example: many Germans believe "it's raining cats and dogs" is a popular idiom in English, just because this was in their textbooks for generations.)

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann: "many Germans believe 'it's raining cats and dogs' is a popular idiom in English, just because this was in their textbooks for generations" - there's still a difference between claiming that something is downright wrong when it actually isn't vs. claiming something is a popular idiom when it is indeed an actual idiom, even though its popularity may be debatable. In general, I agree, and I think it's not at all limited to vocabulary factoids, but also true to other (e.g. cultural) alleged "insider information" from the other side of a language barrier.

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann: na ja, darüber gehen die Minungen auseinander. Die Briten benutzen es nicht merh so oft, aber: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/101280/is-raining-cats-and-dogs-still-used-nowadays

Comment: For another perspective, several years ago, while trying to practice my 30-second introduction/elevator speech for job interviews and the like, I debated whether or not I should introduce myself with "I am X" or "My name is X." Ultimately, I decided to go with "My name is X" because technically speaking, I am so much more than just my name and my name doesn't fully encompass all the things that I am. Technically speaking, when someone says "I am X," what they are really saying is "I am [someone who has been named] X." Right or wrong, this is my distinction between these two choices.

Answer (score 13):

The difference is in the level of formality vs casualness here.

> Ich heiße Fritz Müller

would be a formal, almost stiff way of introducing yourself. Someone presenting himself to a conference auditory he is new to could use this.

> Ich bin der Fritz

is a very casual (but friendly) way of introducing yourself. Fritz thus suggest to use "Du" for addressing him.

> Ich bin Fritz Müller

is somewhat in-between: both formal and to some extent casual.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68131/discussion-on-answer-by-christian-geiselmann-what-if-someone-says-ich-bin-as-a).

Answer (score 6):

"Ich bin X," in this context is not wrong. It's just not formal German.

It's like the difference in English between saying "Hi," and "Hello." The latter is more common, but using the former isn't an error, or even "odd." It is just "less common" and less formal.

So the answer to your question is, "Nothing much."

Answer (score 6):

When I was in school, at the age of 14, we read the book “Krabat” in the German class. One sentence I remember strongly is:

> Ich bin Krabat, ein Mühlknappe aus dem Koselbruch.

We discussed the difference between “ich heiße” and “ich bin” for quite a long time in class, maybe even a whole lesson. Since then I prefer “ich bin” over “ich heiße”.

The latter sounds technical, like answering a question for specific information, while the former puts emphasis on the person as a complex being. “I am”, I identify with all of my thoughts, my traits, myself.

Most probably, people who had other teachers will have made other experiences.

Comment: That's so funny because I think of these two choices in the exact opposite way.  For example, I am a female, an American, a native English speaker, a student of foreign languages, a university grad, a cat lover, a voter, a Stack Exchange fan.  I am nice, flexible, helpful, conscientious, positive, and creative.  But my _name_ is Lisa.

Answer (score -1):

There's an ever-present danger of a touch, or more than a touch, of arrogance, pride, or self-obsession being either implied or inferred by "Ich bin".

There's more control over this (for better or worse) when it's spoken rather than written. If written, the nuances in its meaning will vary according to context and other evidence.

Comment: Welcome to German.SE. As I'm blank in this topic - do you have any reference where your mentioned aspect is a little bit discussed? Can you link to it & quote the relevant part? Thanks